# How to bind an array of strings to a textbox field in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have an array of strings which I want to bind with a textbox field in HTML code. I am not sure how to iterate through the array to show the values as comma separated list in textbox field.

I have tried:

```
[(ngModel)] = "arrayName"
```

But it is working only if I take out only one element from array.

```
[(ngModel)] = "arrayName[0]"
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" [(ngModel)]="selectedRecipients"name="recpList"/>
```

Array:

```
selectedRecipients = [recp1,recp2]
```

Now I want to show the elements of array(recp1,recp2) to the textbox.

Comment: That’s not how it works, if you want it to work that way you need to map the array into that string value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding ngModel to a method that formats the array as string.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" [ngModel]="formatRecipients(selectedRecipients)"name="recpList"/>
```

and then your formatRecipients method

```
function formatRecipients(recipients){
    return recipients.join()
}
```